# iOS dyld: Symbol not found: _NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, dynamic-island

I'm adding support for LiveActivities/Widgetkit for my iOS app.
I'm still supporting older versions for iOS 14+.
When checking if the user returned to the app through the LiveActivity in my SceneDelegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if #available(iOS 16.2, *), isLiveActivity(activity: userActivity) {
        ...
    } else {
        let _ = handleDynamicLink(url: userActivity.webpageURL)
    }
}
```

with

```
@available(iOS 16.2, *)
public func isLiveActivity(activity: NSUserActivity) -> Bool {
    return activity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity
}
```

Now the issue is no matter how I wrap it in #available(iOS 16.2, *) or even if I don't call `isLiveActivity` at all, just the presence of `NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity` in the code anywhere will, on older iOS versions (tested on simulator only) throw the error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity
```

How am I supposed to include this check if I can't even include the symbol anywhere in my code ?
I would have assumed `NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity` to be a compile time constant, but it seems like it's dynamically looked up and crashes, since it isn't available in older versions of WidgetKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bug in the SDK and recommend you file a bug with Apple about it.

As a workaround you could do:

```
public func isLiveActivity(activity: NSUserActivity) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 16.2, *){
            // workaround; we know that the live activity type is a global
            // variable containing the name of itself as a string via
            // a debug session on iOS 16.2
            return activity.activityType == "NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity"
        }
        return false
    }
```

The reason why I think it is a bug because looking at the documentation, [NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/nsuseractivitytypeliveactivity/?changes=latest_major) we see it marked as iOS 14.0+ but if we were to launch the simulator with debugging (`DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` environmental variable) as per [iOS Crash Dump Analysis](https://faisalmemon.github.io/ios-crash-dump-analysis-book/en/#dynamic-linker-api-usage) we see it complain:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity
  Referenced from: /Users/faisalm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77B3F700-46F7-402C-91D5-11453CD73D23/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/73D71FF5-2E01-46E7-AEE9-C1BF94FC8846/useractivity-expt.app/useractivity-expt
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/WidgetKit.framework/WidgetKit
.
.
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
```

If we were to go into the above `DYLD_ROOT_PATH` we could check using `nm` that the global variable `NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity` is not present because the following command yields no matches:

```
nm '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/WidgetKit.framework/WidgetKit'| grep _NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity
```

So the global variable NSUserActivityTypeLiveActivity needs to be marked properly in the WidgetKit source code as not being available until iOS 16.1.

Comment: thank you for looking into it. I worked around it by not relying on it in general, but I agree just using a hardcoded string for now is probably the way to go.